# Build multi architecture image using docker/buildx in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: docker, ubuntu, azure-devops, buildx

We have a use case in which we are aiming to build a multi architecture image, since that image would be executed in a raspberry (arm) or in one of our local machines (or even virtual). The ultimate goal is to run the image creation within an Azure DevOps pipelines.

The idea is to use the buildx experimental feature of docker which seems a good idea. The pipelines agent runs the pipeline within an Ubuntu VM hosted in Azure, in the internal network.

However, there's been some issues regarding this. The first and foremost is that artifactory base images, which we use to build our own images, are behind the company certificate and this causes some issues fetching them.

Here's the command:

```
docker buildx build --no-cache --platform linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64/v8,linux/amd64 ~/.docker/test/.
```

and the outcome, with a "hello world" Dockerfile that illustrates the point:

```
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM company.private.registry/ubuntu:20.04
   2 |
   3 |     RUN echo 'we are running some # of cool things'
--------------------
error: failed to solve: company.private.registry/ubuntu:20.04: failed to do request: Head "https://company.private.registry/v2/ubuntu/manifests/20.04": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Also, the **docker build** command is pulling the images without problem, the problem is only when using the **buildx**

Has anyone worked with multi architecture image builds? Is there maybe something I'm not considering that I should?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party,

`linux/arm64/v8` <-- This is probably your issue, I believe the manifest for **ArmV8** is just `linux/arm64`

`Platforms: linux/arm64, linux/amd64, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6` <-- `buildx inspect` output from a builder running on an **ArmV8** device